# mask out ocean area in shape file using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mask, shapefile

I draw a temperature distribution with ggplo2 based on a netcdf file and a shape file of world

but I can't mask out the ocean area, what I want is a picture only colored on land area and keep the ocean area blue, the geom_polygon can only fill the land area how to do the opposite  filling?

thx

here is the original code;

```
library(RNetCDF)
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
setwd("F:\\Programing\\Rnetcdf")
f<-open.nc("Soong.nc")

basemap<-readShapeSpatial("world.shp")
head(basemap)
shore <- fortify(basemap)
#shore$long<-shore$long+180
head(shore)

var.inq.nc(f,"TMP_P0_L109_GLL0")
apt<-var.get.nc(f,"APTMP_P0_L103_GLL0")

lon<-var.get.nc(f,"lon_0")
lat<-var.get.nc(f,"lat_0")

newlon<-rep(lon,each=length(lat))
newlat<-rep(lat,length(lon))
newapt<-as.vector(t(apt))

newlon[newlon>180]<-newlon[newlon>180]-360

draw<-as.data.frame(cbind(newlat,newlon,newapt))

finaldraw<-ggplot(data=draw,aes(x=newlon,y=newlat,fill=newapt))+
  geom_raster(interpolate=F)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(7)), na.value = NA) +
  geom_polygon(data = shore, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), color = "black",fill=NA) +
  theme_bw()
```

and this is the picture of the code above

[image]

Comment: replace your `world.shp` with an ocean shapefile such as http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-ocean/ and use `fill = "blue"` in the `geom_polygon` call.

Comment: THX,  I do replaced the shape file which downloaded from the website, but the final picture is quite strange , I also draw a new picture in a GIS-software with the shape file and the same data，two picture is different from each other, it seems that R-pic missed a lot land area such Australia and Greenland, I don't know where is the problem is